# How to enrich dataframe by adding columns in specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two different datasets:

`users`:

```
+-------+---------+--------+
|user_id| movie_id|timestep|
+-------+---------+--------+
|   100 |   1000  |20200728|
|   101 |   1001  |20200727|
|   101 |   1002  |20200726|
+-------+---------+--------+
```

`movies`:

```
+--------+---------+--------------------------+
|movie_id|  title  |         genre            |
+--------+---------+--------------------------+
|   1000 |Toy Story|Adventure|Animation|Chil..|
|   1001 | Jumanji |Adventure|Children|Fantasy|
|   1002 | Iron Man|Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi   |
+--------+---------+--------------------------+
```

How to get dataset in the following format? So I can get user's taste profile, so I can compare different users by their similarity score?

```
+-------+---------+--------+---------+---------+-----+
|user_id|  Action |Adventure|Animation|Children|Drama|
+-------+---------+--------+---------+---------+-----+
|   100 |    0    |    1    |    1    |   1    |  0  |
|   101 |    1    |    1    |    0    |   1    |  0  |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: `merge` and `str.split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Where `df` is the movies dataframe and `dfu` is the users dataframe
- The `'genre'` column needs to be split into a list with [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), and then using [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), transform each element of the list into a row, replicating index values.
- [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) the two dataframes on `'movie_id'`
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `'user_id'` and `'genre'` and aggregate by [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html).
- Shape `final`

  - [`.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) converts the groupby dataframe from long to wide format
  - [`.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) replace `NaN` with `0`
  - [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) changes the numeric values from `float` to `int`
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`**

```py
import pandas as pd

# data
movies = {'movie_id': [1000, 1001, 1002],
          'title': ['Toy Story', 'Jumanji', 'Iron Man'],
          'genre': ['Adventure|Animation|Children', 'Adventure|Children|Fantasy', 'Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi']}

users = {'user_id': [100, 101, 101],
         'movie_id': [1000, 1001, 1002],
         'timestep': [20200728, 20200727, 20200726]}

# set up dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame(movies)
dfu = pd.DataFrame(users)

# split the genre column strings at '|' to make lists
df.genre = df.genre.str.split('|')

# explode the lists in genre
df = df.explode('genre', ignore_index=True)

# merge df with dfu
dfm = pd.merge(dfu, df, on='movie_id')

# groupby, count and unstack
final = dfm.groupby(['user_id', 'genre'])['genre'].count().unstack(level=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

# display(final)
genre    Action  Adventure  Animation  Children  Fantasy  Sci-Fi
user_id                                                         
100           0          1          1         1        0       0
101           1          2          0         1        1       1
```